# Objective-C keep track of my view in subviews array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subview, addsubview

I have a question about memory management.
For example I have an iPhone application that uses multiply programmatically created views.
for example programmatically generated buttons.

```
    UIButton *myButton=[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...; //etc
```

then, normally we add this button to  subviews array:

```
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

then we releasing button.

```
    [myButton release]
```

When I need to remove this button how can I keep track on this button in subviews array?
I know I can do this using tag property but I think exists another way to keep connection with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign it to an instance variable:

```
UIButton *myButton = ...;
[self.view addSubView:myButton];
myInstanceVariable = myButton;
[myButton release];
```

You just need to be careful: as soon as you do something like `[myInstanceVariable removeFromSuperview];` it might get deallocated immediately (if you haven't retained it) and it would then point to invalid memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare somewhere a retain property of `UIButton*` type, that can be assigned with pointer value to your button instance:

```
@interface myclass
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *savedButton;
@end

@implementation myclass
@synthesize savedButton;

- (void) someMethod...
{
  ...
  UIButton *myButton=[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...;
  [self.view addSubview:myButton];
  self.savedButton = myButton;
  [myButton release];
  ...
}
...
@end
```